# How to open new tab in existing terminal session and using keyboard shortcut / modifying global settings

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

Keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> opens a new terminal window on `Linux`.
By default it opens `1` new terminal window.

1. Is there a way how to customize how many new `tabs` are going to be opened ? 
   e.g. by using this shortcut it will open 2 tabs by default
2. What is the right `keyboard shortcut` to open a new tab in existing terminal ?

   - I want to have 2 tabs opened and switch between them with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>Page up</kbd>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

gnome-terminal is the default terminal application on Ubuntu.   It does have a command line option that should help:

```
--tab    Open a new tab in the last-opened window with the default profile
```

so you could create a custom keyboard shortcut with the command

```
gnome-terminal --tab
```

If you wanted to open two tabs you could create a script file like:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --tab
gnome-terminal --tab
```

Then call that script file from your keyboard shortcut.

Comment: That still opens a new terminal. It does not open a tab in an existing terminal as requested : "open a new tab in existing terminal".

Comment: It does not appear to work with Gnome Terminal version 3.20.2 which is what I currently have installed under Ubuntu.   It has worked with earlier versions.

Comment: It looks like it may have never worked and they removed the help that says it did: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83203

Comment: Works in terminal, but doesn't work as keyboard shortcut (open new window). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191093/3337089  Didn't work for me though

Answer (score 19):

Run `gnome-terminal` command and add as many `--tab` options as you need.
For instance, `gnome-terminal --tab --tab --tab` will get you a new window with three tabs. Assign the command to a keyboard shortcut to achieve what your goal.

To open a new tab interactively use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: Super advanced usage of this, including detailed work-arounds to overcome the fact that the `gnome-terminal` `--title` and `--command` options are now unfortunately deprecated: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563.

Answer (score 8):

CTRL + ALT + T (Open New Terminal)
CTRL + SHIFT + T (Open New Tab in the terminal(Note you should not present on browser while executing this shortcut otherwise last closed browser tab will be opened)

gnome-terminal (open New Terminal)
gnome-terminal --tab (open New tab in the terminal)

ALT + (tab number)   ex: ALT + 1 (change to First Terminal tab)
                         Alt + 2 (change to second Terminal Tab)

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + T` is very useful! Thank you!

Comment: lol  easiest solution ever XD

Answer (score 1):

From the existing gnome terminal, right click and select `Preferences`, you will see the keyboard shortcuts settings on `Global` -> `Shortcuts`.

[image: The screenshot]